# Why did the Xindi test a mini-superweapon on Earth?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise

At the end of season two in *Star Trek: Enterprise*, the Xindi attack earth with their prototype mini-superweapon, killing 7 million humans and some alligators.  This precipitates all the events of season three, where the protagonists attempt to stop the real superweapon.

However, why did the Xindi show their hand that they had it in for the humans?  Why not test it on some other uninhabited moon like they did later, then show up only when they were ready to go?

Comment: This is just the first of many serious flaws I feel showed up in the Xindi plotline that dragged on waaaay too long.  (Seriously, did anyone think there was any point in turning in until the last 15 minutes of the last episode to see Earth be saved?)  It could have been just as easily tested on an uninhabited planet near them as on Earth, so many light years away.  (Besides, there's just so many better ways to destroy an entire planet than by wiping the surface.)

Comment: Because if they waited until they finished the real superweapon and managed to destroy Earth, there wouldn't be a season 3 or 4.

Comment: they did it for the lulz

Comment: @Kevin: But if they were smarter and were a credible foe, people might have stuck around for a season 5 or 6 or 7!

Comment: The whole Xindi thing was a mess.  If Enterprise had gone some other direction, it might have been at least marginally good, but with the whole Xindi thing Enterprise turned into a big train wreck that it never recovered from.

Comment: @Brian, aside from the overarching, seemingly inane plot, I liked the spirit of the third season; markedly darker, less rehashing of old mythos, more "new worlds and new civilizations" (I think I misquoted that...shows how much of a trekkie I am)

Comment: I didn't mind season 3. I think the problem was that the Xindi plot was too intense. After they foiled the Xindi plot, how could you raise the stakes? Seriously, who cares about season 4 now that the threat to Earth is over?

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch: Yes, you're right and I agree.  While I agree with Nick that I liked the darker feel and the new planets, it was a stupid plot from the start, especially since the whole, "We have to stop them from destroying us" plot was just WAY too predictable.  Season 4 was much better, though.

Comment: I love the fact that the 3rd season is so polarizing. There were some plot holes large enough to fly a starship through, the "Vulcan neuropressure" plot thread was insulting and absurd, and you could argue as to whether the darker, more intense stuff was even Trek at all, but they definitely broke some new ground on that season.

Comment: Considering the the Reptilians fondness of torture, it isn't unlikely that they sent the test weapon just to scare the hell out of the humans, and to make them aware of their 'inevitable' defeat.

Comment: I believe a big part of their intent was to test Earth's defenses, i.e., check for orbital weapons platforms or energy shields that would stop the main weapon from working. I could have sworn this was stated at some point but now I can't find a reference.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The Xindi were not in the business of annihilating whole planets for the fun of it, they were planning on destroying Earth because the Sphere Makers told them that—if they didn't—Earth would do the same to them in the future.

So they spent a lot of time developing the weapon, which needed to be tested, and they needed intelligence on Earth. Testing the destructive power of the weapon on any planet with life and sending a probe that would likely to be caught wouldn't have been prudent.

But killing two birds with one stone by sending a probe with the prototype weapon and testing it on the planet they hoped to destroy anyway makes sense, especially if you operate under the assumption that there would've been no way for Earth to know it was you.

That is, in "[The Xindi](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Xindi_%28episode%29)", the council is [shocked to find out](http://www.chakoteya.net/Enterprise/53.htm) that *Enterprise* was looking for them in the expanse:

> **Xindi-Humanoid:** It could simply be a coincidence.
>   **Xindi-Reptilian:** You're being naive. Their planet is fifty light years away. It is not a coincidence.
>   **Xindi-Humanoid:** How do you know your contacts gave you accurate information?
>   **Xindi-Insectoid:** It's the beginning of an invasion. Hundreds of Earth ships will follow.
>   **Xindi-Humanoid:** They have no way of knowing that we launched the probe.

Of course, the only way Earth knew who perpetrated the attack was because [Future Guy](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Future_Guy) told Archer about it in "[The Expanse](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Expanse_%28episode%29)".

There's also the matter of the different philosophies amongst the Xindi species. The Humanoids like Degra wanted to proceed slowly, but the Reptilians and the Insectoids wanted to attack Earth as soon as possible. They were constantly giving the other races ultimata to finish the weapon quickly lest the resort to other tactics. For example, in "[Rajiin](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Rajiin_%28episode%29)", the [Reptilians threaten to use bioweapons](http://www.chakoteya.net/Enterprise/56.htm) when Degra talks of the delays in the project:

> **Xindi-Reptilian:** And what of your work, Degra?
>   **Degra:** I haven't been able to assess how much data was lost. This will obviously delay us.
>   **Xindi-Insectoid:** How long?
>   **Degra:** Months perhaps. I'm not certain.
>   **Xindi-Insectoid:** The humans have been through our space!
>   **Xindi-Reptilian:** They attacked a trellium mine. We cannot wait any longer.
>   **Degra:** Think what you're asking me to do. Build a weapon to destroy an entire world. Do you understand how difficult, how dangerous this project is?
>   **Xindi-Reptilian:** Are you saying you're not up to the task?
>   **Xindi-Aquatic:** Dissension will solve nothing. We knew there could be setbacks.
>   **Xindi-Arboreal:** I agree. We are too far along to change our plan.
>   **Xindi-Humanoid:** Besides, we have no alternative.
>   **Xindi-Reptilian:** You know that isn't true.
>   **Xindi-Humanoid:** That option has been discussed and rejected.
>   **Xindi-Insectoid:** Not by all of us.
>   **Xindi-Reptilian:** Perhaps it is time to reconsider our colleagues' proposal.
>   **Xindi-Humanoid:** We do not have enough information about the humans!
>   **Xindi-Reptilian:** That can be remedied.
>   **Xindi-Aquatic:** It's too dangerous.
>   **Xindi-Arboreal:** I agree. Degra deserves more time.
>   **Xindi-Aquatic:** But if we do not see some progress soon, we'll have no choice but to consider all our options.

And we learn in "[Azati Prime](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Azati_Prime_%28episode%29)" that it was a Reptilian who manned the probe that attacked Earth: it's not inconceivable it was the Repitilians who pushed for a "live fire" test ahead of the finished product.

Comment: What do you mean by "and they needed intelligence on Earth" and "Testing the destructive power of the weapon on any planet with life and sending a probe that would likely to be caught wouldn't have been prudent."?